# How to check if (multiple) words found in string then

Tags: php, arrays, string, if-statement, strpos

```
public static function likecheck($str, $searchTerm) {
    $searchTerm = strtolower($searchTerm);
    $str = strtolower($str);
    $pos = strpos($str, $searchTerm);
    if ($pos === false)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

it works fine to match any single word from $str

```
$found = App\Helper::likecheck('Developers are very good','very');
if($found){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

But I want to check by giving more words separated by commas, if any of the words is found then return true

LIKE:

```
$found = App\Helper::likecheck('Developers are very good','very, good, gentle');
if($found){
    echo 'found';
}
```

But it does not as it can check only one word.

Comment: I will recommend you to pass array instead of comma separated string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend you to pass an array instead of single or comma separated string.

As well as recommend to use `explode()` and `array_intersect()`

```
public static function likecheck($str, $searchTerm =array()) {
    
    $explodedString = explode(' ', strtolower($str));
    $searchTerm = array_map('strtolower', $searchTerm);
    
    if(count(array_intersect($explodedString,$searchTerm)) > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```